# Kotlin complains about this (Unexpected Tokens)

Tags: kotlin, token

In the following Kotlin code

```
   editTextUsername = EditText findViewById(R.id.email_edittext)
```

and the error is :

Error:(70, 35) Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

but i can not understand what did i do wrong.

Comment: Casts in Kotlin use the `as` operator: `findViewById(...) as EditText`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to specify the type of a variable, you can do it like this:

```
val editTextUsername: EditText = findViewById(R.id.email_edittext)
```

If you're below API level 26, and need a cast:

```
editTextUsername = findViewById(R.id.email_edittext) as EditText
```

If you already have the generic `findViewById` method because you're on a newer API level:

```
editTextUsername = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.email_edittext)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are finding and casting view inside activity

```
editTextUserName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.<id>) as EditText
```

or inside fragment use the ff

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);

editTextUserName = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.<id>) as EditText
```